# How to mutate a column containing the factor for each feature in dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that is basically a response of PHQ-9 questionnaire. Where in there are 9 columns which have factors "Not at all", "Sometimes", "Several Days", "More than half the days", "Nearly everyday". The scores of which are 0, 1, 1, 2, 3 respectively. 
The response to all the 9 questions finally gives a PHQ score out of 27.

In my dataset, I however have the responses to these questions stored as :

> $ Interest           : Factor w/ 5 levels "More than half the days",..: 1 4 2 2 4 5 4 4 4 5 ...

Now what I actually want is another column adjacent to each feature like the above which contains the corressponding score. Moreover, at the end I want to calculate the result using these factor scores at the end to give the depression score.

This is the output I am looking at:

```
Interest    I_Factor Pleasure        P_factor  Score 
Not at all    0      Nearly Everyday  2          2
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: you can use recode function in R

Comment: @Hunaidkhan Doesn't the recode function overwrite the values?

Comment: @PrajwalKharel recode in a new column rather than changing the same

Answer (score 0):

Creating a simulated dataframe for you:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005"),
             PHQ_1 = c("Not at all", "Not at all", "Sometimes", "Sometimes", "Several Days"),
             PHQ_2 = c("Sometimes", "Sometimes", "Several Days", "More than half the days", "Nearly everyday"))
```

Using `mutate_at` to select the questionnaire items for you, and then mass applying `recode` from the `psych` package to change the likert scales from factors to numeric. Giving a "name" for the new columns and they would not replace the old columns (e.g. "numeric_columns" in the example below).

Once this is done, using `mutate` again to compute the row sums and put it into a new column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(psych)

test <- df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(PHQ_1:PHQ_2), funs(numeric_columns = recode(., 
                                       "Not at all" = 0,
                                       "Sometimes" = 1,
                                       "Several Days" = 1,
                                       "More than half the days" = 2,
                                       "Nearly everyday" = 3))) %>%
  mutate(total = rowSums(select(., contains("numeric_columns"))))
```

The sample output is as follows. The original columns are retained and you have the new columns in numeric format as well as the total score of the questionnaire.

```
   id        PHQ_1                   PHQ_2 PHQ_1_numeric_columns PHQ_2_numeric_columns total
1 001   Not at all               Sometimes                     0                     1     1
2 002   Not at all               Sometimes                     0                     1     1
3 003    Sometimes            Several Days                     1                     1     2
4 004    Sometimes More than half the days                     1                     2     3
5 005 Several Days         Nearly everyday                     1                     3     4
```